# After Ble connected, received lastValueStream data notify activating

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

After the Ble device connection is complete, data reception delay occurs when data is received to the lastValueStream by activating notify.

Next is the connection and received data code.

Future connect() async {
Future? returnValue;

```
try{
  await widget.device.connect(autoConnect: false)
      .timeout(const Duration(milliseconds: 15000), onTimeout: () {
    returnValue = Future.value(false);
    setBleConnectionState(BluetoothConnectionState.disconnected);
  }).then((data) async {
    bluetoothService.clear();
    if (returnValue == null) {
      await widget.device.requestMtu(25);
      List<BluetoothService> bleServices = await widget.device.discoverServices();
      setState(() {
        bluetoothService = bleServices;
      });
      for (BluetoothService service in bleServices) {
        for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in service.characteristics) {
          if (c.properties.notify && c.descriptors.isNotEmpty) {
            if (!c.isNotifying) {
              try {
                await c.setNotifyValue(true);
                notifyDatas[c.uuid.toString()] = 0;
                c.lastValueStream.listen((value) async {
                  setState(() {
                    int streamData = processNotifyData(value);
                    notifyDatas[c.uuid.toString()] = streamData;
                    if(streamData != 0){
                      dataStreamController.sink.add(DataPoint(DateTime.now(), streamData));
                    }
                  });
                });
              } catch (e) {
                debugPrint('error ${c.uuid} $e');
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      returnValue = Future.value(true);
    }
  });
}catch(e){
}
return returnValue ?? Future.value(false);
```

}

Why occur data delay?